# Can I configure something in VSCode to get javascript intellisense for a js file that imports from an importmap?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, import-maps

I have this ken.html

```
<script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "three": "../../../node_modules/three/build/three.module.js",
                "manimjs": "../../build/manimjs.js"
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I have this ken.js file:

```
import * as MANIMJS from 'manimjs';  // intellisense does not work
//import * as MANIMJS from "../../build/manimjs.js"; // intellisense works good
```

I have tried various settings in jsconfig.json but none work.
I get no intellisense for objects in MANIMJS unless I toggle the commented lines. Is there some way to let VSCode understand that 'manimjs' (from html importmap) is the same file as "../../build/manimjs.js"?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) file and define the following settings

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["../../build/*.js"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work.  Maybe I don't know where to place the jsconfig.json file.
My structure is ManimJSProject/manimjs/examples/files (html and js files)
The VS code workspace is ManimJSProject.